# How can i assign a Keyboard stroke to a button?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text adventure game where the user needs to enter commands to proceed through the game. so instead of them having to click on the GO! button, I want them to just be able to press enter.

How do I assign the Enter key, to that button.

Comment: jquery keypress event https://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Comment: Post the relevant code that you tried.

Comment: I've tried using the OnKeyPress attribute, but i don't know how to actually link that to any of my functions, if that makes sense. 

i'm new to coding the link you sent me doesn't make an awful lot of sense..

Comment: TKol is assuming you're using jQuery, which may not be the case. Research JavaScript events, of which there are several key events (keyup, keypress etc). Listen for keypress, for example, then check which key was pressed via the event data, then act accordingly. Start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Answer (score 1):

As noted by other devs, you should really look into [JavaScript events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events).

That said, here is an example event that will listen to the document for the 'Enter' keydown event.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
        console.log('You pressed enter.')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically fire click event on a element. In snippet example below we add a "[Keyup EventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event)" to [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/API/Window) object. In order to make enter captured, you need to first click on somewhere on snippet preview. Because when you click on preview, you will be focused on preview document.

```js
window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('go-button').click();
  }
})
```

```css
#scene {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #999;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#go-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  color: #eee;
  font-size: x-large;
  border-radius: 55%;
}

#go-button span{
  font-size: small;
}

#go-button:hover {
  background-color: #729dee;
}
```

```html
<div id="scene">
  <button onclick="alert('Go clicked')" id="go-button" type="button"> Go! <br> <span> [Enter] </span> </button>
</div>
```